# collapsible navigation twitter bootstrap not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to get my navigation bar to collapse however it does not work. I have read other peoples replies to the same problem on this site but I still can't get it to work. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">   
  <head>   
    <meta charset="utf-8">   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TitleHere</title>   
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head> 
  <body>  

    <div class="container">

      <header class="row">
        <div class="span12">
          <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
              <a href="#" class="brand">BrandHere</a>
              <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a> 
              <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
                  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="row" id="main-content">
        <div class="span12"></div>
      </div>

      <footer class="row"></footer>

    </div>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
  </body> 
</html>
```

The location of the files and the paths in the src tags are correct so I am not sure why it is not working. I have tried the website in both Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: check for js errors in your console

Comment: Chrome doesn't report any errors in the Console

Comment: managed to fix by adding this line in header ` <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">`